# Cannot connect access database using c++,odbc

Tags: c++, odbc, ms-access-2007

The rc return -1 but i can't get any error message and status after calling SQLGetDiagRec

```
SQLRETURN rc;
SQLHENV henv1 = NULL;
SQLHDBC hdbc1= NULL;
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv1);
SQLSetEnvAttr(henv1,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3,0);
rc =SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv1, &hdbc1);

char szDSN[256] = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN=data;DBQ=D:\\data\\data.accdb;";
char out[256];
int     iConnStrLength2Ptr;
rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc1, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)&szDSN, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)&out,255, (SQLSMALLINT*)&iConnStrLength2Ptr, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

SQLWCHAR SQLState[256];
SQLINTEGER NativeErrorPtr;
SQLWCHAR MessageText[256];
SQLSMALLINT TextLengthPtr = 255;
SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_ENV,henv1,1,(SQLWCHAR*)SQLState,&NativeErrorPtr,(SQLWCHAR*)MessageText,255,&TextLengthPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not really showing the error testing part of the code. After SQLDriverConnect you should check !SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc). The call to SQLGetDiagRec is on the environment handle but the error occurred on a connection handle so you probably want to change your call to SQLGetDiagRec.